# how to count grand total of product price in custom listview

Tags: android

how to calculate final amount of products in custom listview. In my program it takes only last item and perform also and show it only last items multiplication.please solve my problem.I am new in android.

[image]

> Adapter code

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<Product> productdata;
        ArrayList<Product> itemprice;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context c;
        public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> templist, ArrayList<Product> price) {//  super(context,templist);
            this.productdata=templist;
            this.c=context;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.itemprice=price;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return productdata.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return productdata.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_qty,tv_row_product_name,tv_row_product_rate,tv_row_product_qty,tv_totalprice,tv_value ;
            ImageView imageView;
            ImageButton imgbtnp, imgbtnm;
            Button button_Chk;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productqty);
                viewHolder.tv_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userqty);
                viewHolder.imgbtnp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
                viewHolder.imgbtnm = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                viewHolder.button_Chk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chkout);
                viewHolder.tv_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_value);
                viewHolder.tv_totalprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_totalprice);
                viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            Product pp = productdata.get(position);
            Log.d(Config.tag, "url : " + "uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl());

            Picasso.with(this.c)
                    .load("http://www.sureshkirana.com/uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);

            viewHolder.tv_row_product_name.setText(pp.getProductName());
            viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate.setText("Rs. " + pp.getProductPrice() + "/-");
            viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty.setText(pp.getProductQty() + "kg");




            viewHolder.imgbtnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Product pp = productdata.get(position);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (pp.getUserQty() < 10)
                        pp.setUserQty(pp.getUserQty() + 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1
                    productdata.set(position, pp);// updating the itemList to that new item with incremented quantity
                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(pp.getUserQty()));
                    ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.imgbtnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Product pp = productdata.get(position);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (pp.getUserQty() > 0)
                        pp.setUserQty(pp.getUserQty() - 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1
                    productdata.set(position, pp);// updating the itemList to that new item with incremented quantity
                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(String.valueOf(pp.getUserQty()));
                    ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            int finalamount =0;
            for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < itemprice.size(); temp1++)
            pp = itemprice.get(temp1);
            {
                pp.setProductSalePrice(pp.getProductPrice() * pp.getUserQty());
                finalamount += pp.getProductSalePrice();
                viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+finalamount);
            }
            Log.d(Config.tag, "Total Price is:" + finalamount);
            ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
          return view;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: show us your effort .

Comment: Where you update checkout item amount code ?

Comment: Try this way when ever any item quantity change first store quantity state on respective product data then try to iterate all productdata list and calculate all item amount and quantity from product data latest updation.

Comment: When a person selects a product, add a product id to an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<Product> productdata;
        ArrayList<Product> itemprice;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context c;
        public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> templist, ArrayList<Product> price) {//  super(context,templist);
            this.productdata=templist;
            this.c=context;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.itemprice=price;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return productdata.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return productdata.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_qty,tv_row_product_name,tv_row_product_rate,tv_row_product_qty,tv_totalprice,tv_value ;
            ImageView imageView;
            ImageButton imgbtnp, imgbtnm;
            Button button_Chk;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productqty);
                viewHolder.tv_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userqty);
                viewHolder.imgbtnp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
                viewHolder.imgbtnm = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                viewHolder.button_Chk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chkout);
                viewHolder.tv_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_value);
                viewHolder.tv_totalprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_totalprice);
                viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            Product pp = productdata.get(position);
            Log.d(Config.tag, "url : " + "uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl());

            Picasso.with(this.c)
                    .load("http://www.sureshkirana.com/uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);

            viewHolder.tv_row_product_name.setText(pp.getProductName());
            viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate.setText("Rs. " + pp.getProductPrice() + "/-");
            viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty.setText(pp.getProductQty() + "kg");




            viewHolder.imgbtnp.setOnClickListener(new PlusButtonListener(position,pp,viewHolder.tv_totalprice));

            viewHolder.imgbtnm.setOnClickListener(new MinusButtonListener(position,pp,viewHolder.tv_totalprice));

            int finalamount =0;
            for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < itemprice.size(); temp1++)
            pp = itemprice.get(temp1);
            {
                pp.setProductSalePrice(pp.getProductPrice() * pp.getUserQty());
                finalamount += pp.getProductSalePrice();
                viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+finalamount);
            }
            Log.d(Config.tag, "Total Price is:" + finalamount);
            ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            class PlusButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;
        Product data;
TextView totalTextView;
        Listener(int position,Product data,TextView totalTextView) {
            this.position = position;
    this.totalTextView=totalTextView;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         if (data.getUserQty() < 10)
         {
                        data.setUserQty(data.getUserQty() + 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1

                    totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(data.getUserQty()));
                    data.setProductSalePrice(data.getProductPrice() * data.getUserQty());

                viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+data.getProductSalePrice());
            }
        }
    }
        class MinusButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;
        Product data;
TextView totalTextView;
        Listener(int position,Product data,TextView totalTextView) {
            this.position = position;
    this.totalTextView=totalTextView;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if (data.getUserQty() > 0)
          {
                        data.setUserQty(data.getUserQty() - 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1

                 totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(data.getUserQty()));

                data.setProductSalePrice(data.getProductPrice() * data.getUserQty());

                viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+data.getProductSalePrice());
            }
           }       

        }
    }
        public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            ArrayList<Product> productdata;
            ArrayList<Product> itemprice;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            Context c;
            public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> templist, ArrayList<Product> price) {//  super(context,templist);
                this.productdata=templist;
                this.c=context;
                this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.itemprice=price;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return productdata.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return productdata.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            class ViewHolder {
                TextView tv_qty,tv_row_product_name,tv_row_product_rate,tv_row_product_qty,tv_totalprice,tv_value ;
                ImageView imageView;
                ImageButton imgbtnp, imgbtnm;
                Button button_Chk;
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder viewHolder;
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.tv_row_product_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
                    viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productqty);
                    viewHolder.tv_qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userqty);
                    viewHolder.imgbtnp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
                    viewHolder.imgbtnm = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                    viewHolder.button_Chk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chkout);
                    viewHolder.tv_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_value);
                    viewHolder.tv_totalprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_totalprice);
                    viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    view.setTag(viewHolder);

                } else {
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                Product pp = productdata.get(position);
                Log.d(Config.tag, "url : " + "uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl());

                Picasso.with(this.c)
                        .load("http://www.sureshkirana.com/uploads/product/" + pp.getProductUrl())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);

                viewHolder.tv_row_product_name.setText(pp.getProductName());
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_rate.setText("Rs. " + pp.getProductPrice() + "/-");
                viewHolder.tv_row_product_qty.setText(pp.getProductQty() + "kg");




                viewHolder.imgbtnp.setOnClickListener(new PlusButtonListener(position,pp,viewHolder.tv_totalprice));

                viewHolder.imgbtnm.setOnClickListener(new MinusButtonListener(position,pp,viewHolder.tv_totalprice));

                int finalamount =0;
                for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < itemprice.size(); temp1++)
                pp = itemprice.get(temp1);
                {
                    pp.setProductSalePrice(pp.getProductPrice() * pp.getUserQty());
                    finalamount += pp.getProductSalePrice();
                    viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+finalamount);
                }
                Log.d(Config.tag, "Total Price is:" + finalamount);
                ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                class PlusButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
            private int position;
            Product data;
    TextView totalTextView;
            Listener(int position,Product data,TextView totalTextView) {
                this.position = position;
        this.totalTextView=totalTextView;
                this.data = data;
            }

            @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             if (data.getUserQty() < 10)
             {
                            data.setUserQty(data.getUserQty() + 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1

                        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(data.getUserQty()));
                         for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < itemprice.size(); temp1++)
                pp = itemprice.get(temp1);
                {
                    pp.setProductSalePrice(pp.getProductPrice() * pp.getUserQty());
                    finalamount += pp.getProductSalePrice();
                    viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+finalamount);
                }
                }
            }
        }
            class MinusButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
            private int position;
            Product data;
    TextView totalTextView;
            Listener(int position,Product data,TextView totalTextView) {
                this.position = position;
        this.totalTextView=totalTextView;
                this.data = data;
            }

            @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if (data.getUserQty() > 0)
              {
                            data.setUserQty(data.getUserQty() - 1);// incrementing item quantity by 1

                     totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(data.getUserQty()));
                      for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < itemprice.size(); temp1++)
                pp = itemprice.get(temp1);
                {
                    pp.setProductSalePrice(pp.getProductPrice() * pp.getUserQty());
                    finalamount += pp.getProductSalePrice();
                    viewHolder.tv_totalprice.setText("Rs."+finalamount);
                }
               }       

            }
        }
```

Comment: ok i can again update the code can you show your product class

Comment: I can update the code please try again and let me knw if you get any error